# How do I restart a COM+ application on a remote server from .NET?

Tags: .net, com, comadmin

How do I programmatically restart a COM+ application running on a remote server from code in .NET?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use the ComAdmin API through COM interop.

Put a reference on Windows\System32\Com\ComAdmin.dll, then:

```
COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog catalog = new COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalogClass();
catalog.Connect(servername);
catalog.ShutdownApplication(AppNameOrAppID);
```

You can find the ComAdmin reference in MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683573.aspx).

It's a COM API, and kind of wierd. Eg. you cannot instantiate a COMAdminCatalog, because it's an interface, not a class, so you have to use COMAdminCatalogClass to create a new instance. Use Visual Studio's Object Browser to look around in the COMAdmin namespace to find out these kinds of pitfalls.

EDIT (some note):

Actually, you CAN write

```
COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog catalog = new COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog();
```

and it works which is surprising because COMAdminCatalog is an interface. But it must be a trick of VStudio or the C# compiler, because the resulting assembly contains the following IL:

```
newobj instance void [Interop.COMAdmin]COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalogClass::.ctor()
```

So it somehow found out that the COMAdminCatalogClass must be instantiated, which is strange enough and a bit confusing too. If someone knows how it happens please comment.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks for giving me all the information I need to get underway with tihs.

Comment: It has to do with the CoClass attribute that is applied to the COM Interop's interface. Back in 2009 I found out some unintended uses for the attribute and posted a question about it at http://stackoverflow.com/q/1303717/151249 See the links on Marc Gravell's answer for details