# How to define the default implementation of an interface in c#?

Tags: .net, inheritance, interface

There is some black magic code in c# where you can define the default implementation of an interface.

So you can write

```
var instance = new ISomeInterface();
```

Any pointers?

UPDATE 1: Note that I did not ask if this is a good idea. Just how was it possible to do it.

**UPDATE 2: to anyone seeing the accepted answer.**

- "this should be treated merely as a curiosity." from Marc Gravel ["Newing up" Interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303717/newing-up-interfaces)
- "It's a bad idea to use a tool designed for COM interop to do something completely and utterly different. That makes your code impossible to understand for the next guy who has to maintain it" from Eric Lippert ["Newing up" Interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303717/newing-up-interfaces)
- "While it may work, if it were ever found in production code by a rational coder, it would be refactored to use a base class or dependency injection instead." from Stephen Cleary in a comment below.

Comment: Some articles on this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093536 and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/04/20/chained-user-defined-explicit-conversions-in-c-part-three.aspx

Comment: Is there still no sane way to do this?

Comment: @WilliamJockusch still the only one i know of

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here comes the black magic:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        IFoo foo = new IFoo("black magic");
        foo.Bar();
    }
}

[ComImport]
[Guid("C8AEBD72-8CAF-43B0-8507-FAB55C937E8A")]
[CoClass(typeof(FooImpl))]
public interface IFoo
{
    void Bar();
}

public class FooImpl : IFoo
{
    private readonly string _text;
    public FooImpl(string text)
    {
        _text = text;
    }

    public void Bar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_text);
    }
}
```

Notice that not only you can instantiate an interface but also pass arguments to its constructor :-)

Comment: And with the keyword "CoClass" the google gods are with me again.
http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/08/15/instantiating-interfaces.aspx
http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/08/who-says-you-cant-instantiate-interface.html

Comment: @Simon, those are two blogs I would recommend you tuning your RSS reader to :-)

Comment: @Daren already have them. but all my combinations of "interface default implementation" came up with naught. Signal to noise ratio was not good :)

Comment: @daren kind of funny that the answers saying "it is not possible" are geting upvoted after you posted your answer.

Comment: If I ever saw this in code by a colleague I'd sack them.

Answer (score 3):

Only if `ISomeInterface` is a class.

**Update (for clarification):**

Jon Skeet has [a talk](http://streaming.ndc2010.no/tcs/?id=AFDB4098-C5C8-49DF-8C2A-7E317F63E72D) where he mentions default implementations for interfaces. They are not part of the C# language, though. The talk is about what Jon Skeet would *like* to see in a future version of C#.

For now, the only default implementations are done via (possibly `abstract`) base classes.

Comment: I downvoted all the incorrect answers. because they were incorrect. no rationality about it. See Darins answer

Comment: I saw the "correct" answer. While it may work, if it were ever found in production code by a rational coder, it would be refactored to use a base class or dependency injection instead.

Comment: @Setphen Agreed. edited the question so hopefully no one thinks it is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you refer to Dependency Injection? Where when using DI framework (such as [Ninject](http://ninject.org) or Unity), you can define default instance for each interface and then using it like this:

(assuming you have `IWeapon` interface and `Sword` implements it)

```
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<IWeapon>().To<Sword>();
var weapon = kernel.Get<IWeapon>();
```

But Ninject (and most other IoC frameworks) can do some more clever things, like: let's say we have the class `Warrior` that takes IWeapon as a parameter in its constructor. We can get an instance of `Warrior` from Ninject:

```
var warrior = kernel.Get<Warrior>();
```

Ninject will pass the IWeapon implementation we specified to the `Warrior` constructor method and return the new instance.

Other than that, I don't know of any in-language feature that allows this kind of behavior.

Comment: good suggestion but not what i was looking for.
See Darins Answer

Comment: Yes, I missed the part where you mentioned "black magic" in your question :-)

Thanks for asking this -- I learned something new!