# Interfaces can't be instantiated but is this an exception

Tags: c#, interface, com, office-interop

I'm very surprised after seeing that I actually have to Instantiate an Interface to use the Word Interoop in C#.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
```

The `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application` according to what its XML documentation says is an interface:

[image]

How is it possible, has visual studio confused it with something else? Or what allows this interface to be instantiated?

Comment: Related: [Please explain why I am able to instantiate the "Application" interface in Excel VSTO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11039064)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303717/newing-up-interfaces

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's because it's a COM interface. COM interfaces - and *only* COM interfaces - can be instantiated directly. The runtime will create an instance of the *real* type behind the scenes. Personally I think it's a bit ugly (and I can't *find* any references to it in the C# spec) but there we go.

You can actually *fake* this so that the C# compiler will believe your interface is a COM type without getting COM involved properly... see [my related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093536/how-does-the-c-sharp-compiler-detect-com-types) for details.

Comment: You are a real C# king from my perspective

Answer (score 3):

You can't instantiate an `interface` in c# by definition and `Application` is ***not*** a regular .NET `interface`, but a COM interface. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.application.ASPx):

> This is a .NET interface derived from a COM coclass that is required
>   by managed code for interoperability with the corresponding COM
>   object.

**Now, you're probably asking your self how come?**

well, when the C# compiler identifies that a `System.Runtime.InteropServices.CoClass` attribute is decorating a `interface`, it would automatically use `Activator.CreateInstance` on the provided `type` from the [`CoClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.coclassattribute.coclass%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) property, for example:

`[System.Runtime.InteropServices.CoClass(typeof(Test))]` - 
So a new instance of `Test` will be created.