# connecting to a remote server's com+ using COMAdmin fails

Tags: c#, com+, comadmin

I want to connect to a com+ application that's on the server to uninstall old dlls and install new ones in the com+.

I've tried connecting to the server like suggested here:
[How do I restart a COM+ application on a remote server from .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954830/how-do-i-restart-a-com-application-on-a-remote-server-from-net)

```
COMAdminCatalog objAdmin = new COMAdminCatalog();
objAdmin.Connect(serverIP);
```

but I get an error:
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

I have a ping and can connect to it remotely (using username & password).

Do I need, somehow, to provide it with the username & password? I couldn't find how on the internet (only in a few places saying you should provide user & pass before committing a change).

Thanks a lot in advance for any help :)

Comment: It doesn't like your user account.  Try another one.  Pick one that's known on the remote machine and has enough privileges.  Ask your LAN admin if you need help.

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't like"? what are the requirements for using this code?